# Is this solvable? $x=e^{-6x}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is the equation $x=e^{-6x}$ solvable without a calculator? If so, how? I tried everything I knew but I couldn't get it. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This equation has no elementary solutions, but can be solved in terms of the [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function):

$$x=e^{-6x} \implies \\
x e^{6x}=1 \implies \\
6x e^{6x} = 6 \implies \\
6x = W(6) \implies \\
x = \frac{1}{6}W(6)$$

You can approximate the W function with different methods, for example, [Newtons's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) [Method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Numerical_evaluation):

$$w_{j+1}=w_j-\frac{w_j e^{w_j}-z}{e^{w_j}(1+w_j)}$$
$$W(z) \approx w_k \qquad k\text{ sufficiently big}$$

Comment: I'm not sure calculating Lambert's W function is particularly easy without a calculator...

Comment: Calculating $e^x$ is not particularly easy without a calculator.

Comment: What tools do we have?  Any tables?

Comment: It's ok, all I meant is if this function has an elementary solution or if the only way to find x is to make a computer do it.

Comment: I don't get it. People don't bat an eyelash when the answer they get is $\sin\,1$ or $\log\,\phi$, but they go ape with $W(6)$. Sheesh...

Answer (score 2):

You can get close by successive approximations:

$$f(x):=e^{-6x}-x\implies f'(x)=-6e^{-6x}-1<0\;\;,\;\forall\,x\in\Bbb R\implies $$

there is one unique solution **at most** for $\,f(x)=0\,$.

Now just observe that $\,f(-1)>0\;,\;f(0)<0\implies\,$ the solution is in $\,[-1,0]\,$ , and you can diminish the length of the intervals as much as you like.